# How to calculate explicitly Cheeger constant (also caled Cheeger number or Isoperimetric number)

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to calculate explicitly Cheeger constant (also caled Cheeger number or Isoperimetric number) for a graph G(V, E), but I haven't found any sources, algorithms or examples. I'm using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_(graph_theory)) definition of Cheeger constant:

[image]

where

[image]

The only thing I found in the Internet was inequalities, but not an explicit answer. Is there any ways to get it?

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Most questions mentioning Cheeger are on Theoretical Computer Science, so I guess that's the place to ask: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?q=cheeger

Comment: I will see there... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the isoperimetric number for **general** graphs is a computationally hard problem (NP Hard in strong sense). So there is no algorithms if you are interested in the exact number. (the inequalities you have found give you upper bounds on the isoperimetric number which maybe enough in certain applications).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, @SIRBA Thank you so much!